# Positioning Landsat 8 data in Google Earth

Tags: google-earth, landsat, google-earth-pro

I have some (combined) Landsat 8 TIF files that I want to overlay in Google Earth Pro. I manually set the 4 corner lat/lon coordinates (Properties->Location) to the 8 `CORNER_UL_LAT_PRODUCT, CORNER_UL_LON_PRODUCT,..` values found in the Landsat metadata file. However, the positioning is not quite right (see image).

Do I need different values? I don't think its a problem of rotation.

[image]